# SpriteKit Jitters and set a constant and "per second" PhysicBody velocity

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm writing a top-down car game where the car is moved by setting velocity in didSimulatePhysics method. To set the velocity i use a parameter created with this formula:

```
CGVectorMake(JoyPadRelativePosition.x * maxSpeed,-JoyPadRelativePosition.y * maxSpeed);
```

JoypadRelativePosition hold the amount of accelleration decided by the user and maxSpeed hold the constant value of maximum speed. By this way i can move my car in the right direction and with the right velocity. However sometimes the car or maybe the background "jitter", this is my didSimulatePhysics:

```
- (void)didSimulatePhysics
{
//moving the car
float dx=JoyPadRelativePosition.x*_maxSpeed;
float dy=JoyPadRelativePosition.y*_maxSpeed;
[self.car.physicsBody setVelocity: CGVectorMake(dx,-dy)];

//center the background to car position
CGPoint target = [self pointToCenterViewOn:self.car.position];

CGPoint newPosition = _worldNode.position;
newPosition.x += (target.x - _worldNode.position.x) * 0.1f;
newPosition.y += (target.y - _worldNode.position.y) * 0.1f;

_worldNode.position = newPosition;

}
```

What i think is that i have to move the car and the background considering the different rendering time of each frame,so in my update method i have implemented this:

```
 if (_lastUpdateTime) {
    _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
} else {
    _dt = 0;
}
_lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
```

In this way i know how many milliseconds are passed from the last rendered frame, but now how i can do to set velocity of my car considering the variable joystick value,the maximum speed and the amount of millisecond passed from the last frame? I think that this kind of calculation can remove jitters problem but if there's some others solutions i'll accept it anyway if remove jitterings... I want to move the car by SetVelocity by anyway i have tried to move it by setPosition and the problem remains.

EDIT
i have found some fps drops...i'm trying to find the cause. I have tried to block the framerate to a lower value and now it's better but the jitters are show anyway...Even at 20 fps! So i have to find the cause of this first

Comment: multiplying with delta time will not remove jitter, in fact if you do have a fluctuating framerate it's likely to make matters worse. First check if the jitter is caused by fps drops, for instance have a non-physics sprite move left/right at constant and slow speed using move action and observe (on a device!) whether this movement is smooth or not. If it's not, try and find the source of the framerate drops. If it's smooth, the jitter is caused by something else, for instance try changing velocity in update:  *before* physics simulation runs

Comment: i have edit my question after your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

where speed is

speed is speed of moving background
car speed speed of car 
speed=5
carspeed=10;

```
if (_lastUpdateTime) {
        _deltaTime = interval - _lastUpdateTime;
    } else {
        _deltaTime = 0;
    }
    _lastUpdateTime = interval;

    CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake(speed*(direction),speed*(direction));
    CGPoint bgVelocity1 = CGPointMake(carspeed*(direction), carspeed*(direction));

    CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMake((int)bgVelocity.x * _deltaTime, bgVelocity.y * _deltaTime);
    CGPoint amtToMove1 = CGPointMake((int) bgVelocity1.x * _deltaTime, bgVelocity1.y * _deltaTime)

    self.position = CGPointMake((int)(self.position.x+amtToMove.x), self.position.y+amtToMove.y);
    car.position = CGPointMake((int)(self.position.x+ amtToMove1), self.position.y+ amtToMove1.y);
```

//now car and move with same direction which same delta time

Comment: i have tried but the jitters will show anyway,but i have found a framerate drop in my game